# Изменение свойств объектов формы, переданных в функцию в ArrayList

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist

У меня есть `ArrayList` элементов формы. Хочу передать его в функцию, внутри которой для каждого элемента нужно поменять его свойство `Visible` на `true`. В моём неправильном (логически) коде создаётся новый объект и меняется его свойство. Но мне нужно работать со старым, который лежит в `ArrayList`. То есть `label1` и `textBox1` есть на форме. И нужно так сделать, чтобы они отобразились на форме.

Это мне больше для практического урока нужно, так что прошу не судить строго, мол так никто не делает.

Код C#

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
al.Add(label1);
al.Add(textBox1);
СhangeVisible(al);

public viod СhangeVisible(List <object>temp)
{
    foreach (var x in temp)
    {
        if (x is Label) { Label lb = (Label )x; lb.Visible = true;  }
        if (x is TextBox) { TextBox tb = (TextBox)x; tb.Visible = true; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Visible` — это свойство базового класса `Control`, соответственно, необязательно приводить к конкретным классам, достаточно привести к `Control`.
2. `ArrayList` — это ископаемый класс, в новом коде следует использовать обобщённые коллекции. Так как вы работаете с элементами управления, то разумным выбором будет `List<Control>`.

Итого:

```
var controls = new List<Control> {
    label1,
    textBox1,
};
SetVisible(controls, true);

void SetVisible (IEnumerable<Control> controls, bool value)
{
    foreach (Control control in controls)
        control.Visible = value;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за полезную информацию.
Но вот всё же элементы на форме видимыми не становятся.
Пробовал уже явно указать передачу по ссылке, немного изменив ваш пример. Но результата нет.

var controls = new List<Control> {
                label1,
                textBox1,
            };
SetVisible(ref controls, true); 

  void SetVisible(ref List<Control> controls, bool value)
        {
            foreach (Control control in controls)
                control.Visible = value; }

Comment: @ФедірФіліппов В моём (да и в вашем) **копируются ссылки**, то есть создания новых объектов не возникает. Контролы создаются только с помощью оператора `new`. У вас проблема где-то в другом месте. Для начала убедитесь с помощью отладчика, что этот код вообще выполняется.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Нашёл ошибку. Всё таки утро вечера мудреннее.